# Can I scroll to top of section inside Bootstrap cards created with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, scroll, jsx

I'm trying to scroll to the top of a section created inside a loop in React. I am wanting the page to scroll to the top of the section when the link is clicked. I'm using Bootstrap to create cards that expand when clicked but the page doesn't scroll to that section.

I've created a link so you can see what I mean on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-goldwasser-3jn3t

When you click 'Explore our services' and click some of the options you'll see what I mean.

Within the function called `CollapsingServices`, inside the Home.jsx file, I've created a span element with an id of `scroll-to-${service.name}` which is where I am wanting the page to scroll to when the link is clicked